# Automorphism of a cell complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

An automorphism of a graph $G = (V,E)$ is a permutation $\sigma$ of the vertex set $V$, such that the pair of vertices $(u,v)$ form an edge if and only if the pair $(\sigma(u),\sigma(v))$ also form an edge.

On the other hand we can view a graph as a cell complex with usual topology.
Let  us denote it by $||G||$.
Since $||G||$ is a topological space, we can talk about homeomorphism group of $||G||$.
Recall that a function $f\colon ||G||\to ||G||$  is a homeomorphism if it has the following properties:

1. $f$ is a bijection.
2. $f$ is continuous.
3. $f^{-1}$ is also continuous

Now I am wondering under which condition we can embed $Aut(G)$ into $Homeo(||G||)$.

Comment: Every automorphism $f$ induces a map from $||G||$ to $||G||$. In addition, the inverse of any open interval in an edge is open. So $f$ is also continuous, and the same idea for $f^{-1}$. Do I miss anything?

Comment: @BabakMiraftab open sets in $\Vert G\Vert$ are not just the open subsets of edges, but otherwise the argument is the same.

Comment: @PrudiiArca U R right, the same argument works for any open set here.